# Django: get aggregated value of two multiplied columns

Tags: django, django-orm, django-aggregation

I need to get aggregated value of two columns. So first multiple them together and then get theirs `sum()`. Code below naturally does not work, it is just for clarification.

Is it somehow possible or should I use raw SQL?

```
SomeModel.objects
    .filter(**something)
    .aggregate(Sum('one_column' * 'another_col'))
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need that much raw SQL using [extra()](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra-select-none-where-none-params-none-tables-none-order-by-none-select-params-none).

```
obj = SomeModel.objects.filter(**something).extra(
    select = {'total': 'SUM(one_column * another_column)'},
)
```

Answer (score 3):

As I answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/36024089/4614802
the correct solution depends on django version.

- For django < 1.8 use `.aggregate(Sum('field1', field="field1*field2"))`
- For django >= 1.8 use `.aggregate(Sum(F('field1')*F('field2'))`

Answer (score 1):

This is sparta. In this way, if you want to print it somewhere in a template you have to use something like this:

```
{{ queryset.0.total }}
```

This was correctly answered here: [Django Aggregation: Summation of Multiplication of two fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12165636/django-aggregation-summation-of-multiplication-of-two-fields)

The form is:

```
agg = Task.objects.all().aggregate(total=Sum('field1', field="field1*field2"))
```